# Strikeout variable after updated one has been echoed

Tags: php, html

I am trying to strikeout a variable as part of an IF statement. The topic is a discount system, I would like to know how to strikeout a variable if the statement is true.

```
                    <td><?php echo "&pound;"  .  $total_price . "<br /> <br />";
$conn = connect();

    if(isset($_POST['discountSubmit'])){

    $discountCode = $_POST['discount'];

    $codeCheck = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM discount WHERE code = '$discountCode'");

if(mysqli_num_rows($codeCheck)> 0 && $total_price >= 30.00) {
$row3 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($codeCheck);
$discount_price = $total_price - $row3['discount'];
echo "£" . $discount_price;
} else if 
($total_price <30.00) {
echo "CODE DENIED";
}
}


                    ?>
```

Currently the statement displays both original value and new Total Price, ideally the original $total_price would have strikeouts if possible?

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: How might I go about striking through the old price, displaying the discount applied and then displaying the new total price

Comment: **warning** your code is vulnerable to sql injection attacks!

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-decoration text-decoration: line-through;

Comment: You'll learn more if you try to do it yourself first.

Comment: Its not the issue of striking through, its striking through the old value, unless its because my if statement is in the wrong place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to actually fetch the result. You probably want `mysqli_fetch_assoc`

It should be noted that you are using `$row`, a variable that you have never defined. That's not a good sign!

Comment: Have altered code to `$row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($codeCheck);
$discount_price = $total_price - $row2['discount'];
echo $discount_price;` which now outputs the correct value which in this instance is 22, is it possible to replace the current $total_price value?